# AngularJS Controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have nested views using UIrouter. Below is the code I have right now, which is not working. I want to know where this has went wrong.

app.js

```
angular.module('Myapp', ['ui.router'])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
.state('main', {
          url: '/main',
          templateUrl: 'main.html',

      })
  .state('main.submit', {
      url: '/submit',
      templateUrl: '/main-submit.html',
      controller: 'MyController'
  });
angular.module('Myapp')
.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http) {  
$scope.click = function () {
     $http.get("URL")
     .success(function (response) {
      $scope.condition = response.Data            
  }};
```

main.html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
<a ui-sref=".submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="click()">Submit</a></div>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

main-submit.html:

```
        {{condition}}
```

Is this the right way to call a function in nested view or not?? Will be grateful if anyone can help.

Comment: You have to call the full state, not just ".submit". So do ui-sref="main.submit"

Comment: @gruberb: That didnt solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have written working example as per your requirement, try it

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.0/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script>
            angular.module('Myapp', ['ui.router'])
                .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

                    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');

                    $stateProvider
                        .state('main', {
                            url: '/main',
                            templateUrl: 'main.html'
                        })
                        .state('main.submit', {
                            url: '/submit',
                            templateUrl: 'main-submit.html',
                            controller: 'MyController'
                        });
                })
                .controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http) {  
                    $scope.click = function () {
                        $scope.condition = 'Condition!!!!!!!!';
                    };
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="Myapp">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.html:

```
Home Page YaHoo!!!!!!
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <a ui-sref=".submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="click()">Submit</a>
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

main-submit.html:

```
{{condition}}
```

I hope it would solve your problem.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Code you have given is what i have right now. The main issue is with  $http.get(). How can i get data from url and send it to main-submit.html by clicking on submit in main.html.

Comment: $http.get() service is used to fetch the data which you have already used and should work correctly. And since ".submit" is the sub state of "main" state so whatever the values which main's scope is having can directly be used by template of sub state. And this is what is happening in the above code added by me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about removing the controller assignment for `html.submit`?
Your'e already wrapping you're template with the same controller, that is handling both states.

Comment: Removing that is working with static data..  but {{condition}} from url is not being displayed.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `ng-click`, use `resolve` param in the `state()` method definition to fetch the data.

Your controller would look like this:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.submit = function(){
    //do processing logic
    $state.go('state1');
  };
});
```

And your state definition would look like this:

```
.state( 'state1', {
  url: '/state1',
  views: {
    "content": {
    templateUrl: 'pages/state1.html',
    controller: 'State1Ctrl',
    resolve: {
      state1Data: function(){return $http.get(/*whatever*/);}
    }
  }
  }
})
```

Comment: Bt I need click option for submit in main.html. Think resolve will solve the issue. Want to know how to use resolve here.

Comment: Then use a button and in the `ng-click`, use `$state.go` to transition to the new state.

Comment: It is what data that'll get injected into the controller - I.e. the data that you need for the controller to render the view.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have only one controller the code is fine. I think you may have noticed angular.module('yapp'). This should be angular.module('Myapp').

When you declare one more controller to the parent state then the trickier things happens. You can access all the functions that are there in the parent controller from child controller. But the parent cannot access the functions or variables declared in the child controller.

Comment: Thats a typo, edited my code. Should i use resolve here? thats an informative comment and -1 is not from me.